# How to merge Dictionarys from typescript-collection?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, collections, merge

I have installed the typescript-collection package to my Angular project to use the Dictionary type.
I want to save all latest posts from Socialmedia in a Dictionary with the Date the image was posted. After this I want to merge alle the Dictionarys into one Dictionary.

```
let TwitterPosts = this.getLatestTwitterPosts();
let InstagramPosts = this.getLatestInstagramPosts();
let FacebookPosts = this.getLatestsFacebookPosts();
```

The getLatests[type]Posts-Methods are like this:

```
const type = 'twitter';
let TwitterPosts = new Collections.Dictionary<number, PostSocialmediaFeedComponent>();
for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
  let PostedDate: Date;
  let url: string;
  // USING THE API TO GET THE VALUES
  TwitterPosts.setValue(count, new PostSocialmediaFeedComponent(url, PostedDate, type));
}
return TwitterPosts;
```

Comment: Just use a simple object and merging is trivial and syntactically supported at that. don't waste your time

Comment: Could you be more specific on what I should exactly do? I do not really understand your answer.

Comment: It wouldn't be much of an answer because it would avoid your question by suggesting that you not use the library. I can answer if you like however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple object and merging becomes trivial and syntactically supported at that. Don't waste your time with complex libraries you don't need.

```
const type = 'twitter';
const twitterPosts: {[key: number]: PostSocialmediaFeedComponent} = {};
for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
  // USING THE API TO GET THE VALUES
  twitterPosts[count] = new PostSocialmediaFeedComponent(url, PostedDate, type);
}
return TwitterPosts;
```

In addition to simplifying dependencies and making your code more straightforward, using objects gives you syntactic support for trivial merging.

```
const twitterPosts = this.getLatestTwitterPosts();
const instagramPosts = this.getLatestInstagramPosts();
const facebookPosts = this.getLatestsFacebookPosts();

const merged = {
  ...twitterPosts,
  ...instagramPosts,
  ...facebookPosts
};
```

This is syntactic sugar for the built in ECMAScript standard library functionality of `Object.assign`

```
const merged = Object.assign({}, twitterPosts, instagramPosts, facebookPosts);
```